# Width of images inside of a table-cell in firefox misbehaving

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have the following table:

```
<table>
    <tbody>     
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <a href="#"><img src="http://www.sherv.net/cm/emoticons/cats/cat-headphones-smiley-emoticon.gif" /></a> 
                <a href="#"><img src="http://www.beaukit.com/catgrpbl.jpg" /></a>   
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and the following CSS:

```
table {
    width: 40%;
    background-color:grey;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0.8em 0;
    max-height: 800px !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto;
}
```

See [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyK9N/3/)

What I want is that the pictures in the cell fill its width if they are bigger than the cell itself. In case the pictures are smaller, they should keep maintain their native width expressed via `max-width`. This seems to work well in Chrome, but when I try it in firefox the bigger pictures stretch the width of the cell.

While, if I change the width of the images to: `width: 100% !important;`, the smaller picture are streched to fill the cell (see table.two).

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding

```
table {
 table-layout:fixed;
}
```

Table cells don't behave like block elements, their widths and heights are defined by the content inside them. From the I.E. [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531161%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

auto: Default. Column width is set by the widest unbreakable content in the column cells.

fixed: Table and column widths are set either by the sum of the widths on the col objects or, if these are not specified, by the width of the first row of cells. If no width is specified for the table, it renders by default with width=100%.

Answer (score 0):

You have use width auti !important which you should not be to

```
 table tr, table tr td{
     width:100%
 }
 table tr td a{
   width:100%;
   display:block;
 }
 img {
     width: 100%;
  }
```

[Check on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EyK9N/6/)